# change inner html on click and then change back on click with Jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been self-learning for a couple of months and put [this](https://codepen.io/wilx2rt/pen/wrLZVQ?editors=0010) together for an online challenge on one of the platforms that I use.
I've managed to change the inner HTML of an element with Jquery on click, but can't figure out how to change it back to what it was on click again.

**How can I make it so that the first click on the .button changes the HTML one way and the sound click changes it back and the interaction can be repeated without reloading the page?**

```
// curent temp, day high and day low
  var temp = json.main.temp.toFixed(1);
  var tempLo = json.main.temp_min.toFixed(1);
  var tempHi = json.main.temp_max.toFixed(1);
  //temperatures converted to farenheit
  var tempF = (temp * (9 / 5) + 32).toFixed(1);
  var tempLoF = (tempLo * (9 / 5) + 32).toFixed(1);
  var tempHiF = (tempHi * (9 / 5) + 32).toFixed(1);
  //default temperature display in celcius on document ready
  $(".temp").html(temp + "&deg;C");
  $(".temp-low").html(tempLo + "&deg;C");
  $(".temp-high").html(tempHi + "&deg;C");

  $(".button").click(function(){
    $(".temp").html(tempF+ "&deg;F");
    $(".temp-low").html(tempLoF+ "&deg;F");
    $(".temp-high").html(tempHiF+ "&deg;F");
  });
```

For more context, see the link above.

Comment: just remember the old value. Where do you struggle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remember the old values (there is no need for this when I understand your code right, because both values are already stored in the tempX Variables) and use a trigger to check which is shown at the moment:

```
var celsius = false;
$(".button").click(function(){
  if(celsius) {
    $(".temp").html(tempF+ "&deg;F");
    $(".temp-low").html(tempLoF+ "&deg;F");
    $(".temp-high").html(tempHiF+ "&deg;F");
  } else {
    $(".temp").html(temp+ "&deg;C");
    $(".temp-low").html(tempLo+ "&deg;C");
    $(".temp-high").html(tempHi+ "&deg;C");
  }
  celsius = !celsius;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty straightforward, works well and learned something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the button attribute/data to store the current metric and change/switch on every click with an initial setup

```
function setTime() {
  var colon = ":";
  var now = new Date();
  var hours = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  var seconds = now.getSeconds();
  //Display seconds & minutes with two digits if < 10
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  // display current time in innerHTML of #time
  var timeNow = `${hours}${colon}${minutes}${colon}${seconds}`;
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeNow;
}
//update setTime every 1000ms
setInterval(setTime, 1000), setTime();

// diplay .title and .sub at the top of the page
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "FCC";
document.getElementById("sub").innerHTML = "Weather App";

$(document).ready(function() {
  //Get Locatiion and declare in var lat and long
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    //add lat and long to URL with template literals
    var weatherApiURL = `https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}`;
    // Get wheather object
    $.getJSON(weatherApiURL, function(json) {
      //disolay location on page
      document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = json.name;
      //display weather icon
      var iconURL = json.weather[0].icon;
      document.getElementById("icon").src = iconURL;
      // display weather condition description (i.e. cloudy, sunny etc.)
      document.getElementById("condition").innerHTML =
        json.weather[0].description;
      // display curent temp, day high and day low
      var temp = {
        'C' : json.main.temp.toFixed(1),
        'F' : (json.main.temp.toFixed(1) * (9 / 5) + 32).toFixed(2)
      };
      var tempLo = {
        'C' : json.main.temp_min.toFixed(1),
        'F' : (json.main.temp_min.toFixed(1) * (9 / 5) + 32).toFixed(1)
      };
      var tempHi = {
        'C' : json.main.temp_max.toFixed(1),
        'F' : (json.main.temp_max.toFixed(1) * (9 / 5) + 32).toFixed(1)
      };

      // initial setup
      var old = $('.button').attr('data-metric');
      switch(old) {
        case 'F':
          metric = 'F';
          break;
        case 'C':
          metric = 'C';
          break;
        default:
          metric = 'C';
          break;
      }

      //default temperature display in celcius on document ready
      $(".temp").html(temp[metric] + "°" + metric);
      $(".temp-low").html(tempLo[metric] + "°" + metric);
      $(".temp-high").html(tempHi[metric] + "°" + metric);

      $(".button").click(function() {
        switch($(this).attr('data-metric')) {
          case 'C':
            metric = 'F';
            break;
          case 'F':
          default:
            metric = 'C';
            break;
        }
        $('.button').attr('data-metric', metric);
        $(".temp").html(temp[metric] + "°" + metric);
        $(".temp-low").html(tempLo[metric] + "°" + metric);
        $(".temp-high").html(tempHi[metric] + "°" + metric);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

And following the html code. Notice the `data-metric="C"`, this is the attribute that stores the current metric

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="clock">
    <h1 id="title"></h1>
  <h2 id="sub"></h2>
    <h1 id="time"></h1>
    <h3 id="location"></h3>
    <img src="" alt="" id="icon">
    <h3 id="condition"></h3>
    <div class="temp-box">
      <h3 class="temp"></h3>
      <div class="hilo">
        <div class="temp-hilo">
          <h5 class="temp-low"></h5><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="temp-hilo">
          <h5 class="temp-high"></h5><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button data-metric="C" class="button">&deg;C&nbsp;/&nbsp;&deg;F</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYGpzz

Comment: thanks, nice use of data- it's gonna take me a bit to understand it all at my skill level but will look into it.

Comment: Sure, keep in mind that with this method the value follows the element and can be used to make it as a module